# sql-Locks concept in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know about the lock concept in sqlserver
 why it is used ? and with any example .is there any pdf or ppt pls specify that

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. Have you read the BOL section already? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187101.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this is too broad a topic to cover in a post.

However to get you started on your learning I would recommend reading through the relevant content in SQL Server Books Online as Martin Smith suggests in the comments.

If you want to get hands on, an excellent book that has a great Chapter that covers the concepts that are involved in the subject of locks (as well as latches) is [Professional SQL Server 2008 Internals and Troubleshooting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484284).

I can't speak highly enough about this title (and no I'm not on the payroll :-) ) It's one of those books that you will always want to keep close to hand so you may return to it when you want to look up something or refresh you memory on a detailed topic, such as SAN storage considerations for the DBA, How does the query processor work, How does SQL Server manage Memory or what Performance Counters you should be monitoring.